# How to include Javadoc and source code with dependency

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I currently use the JSoup dependency into Visual Studio Code, but I don't have the Javadoc or the source code of Jsoup in my Visual Studio Code:

### The dependency

```xml
    <dependency>
      <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/ -->
      <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
      <version>1.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

### The result

#### JavaDoc

[image]

The javadoc is not shown

#### Source

[image]

The source is not shown

### Question

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

The `JavaDoc` and `Sources` of JSoup dependency are available here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.13.1/

JSoup included the Javadoc in their code:
https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.java

Comment: Did you check whether a `javadoc` or `sources` exists in the repository?

Comment: Yes Jsoup has `javadoc` and `sources`: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.13.1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
<dependency>
  <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/ -->
  <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
  <version>1.13.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/ -->
  <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
  <version>1.13.1</version>
  <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/ -->
  <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
  <version>1.13.1</version>
  <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you! Do know if it's possible to configure this directly in Visual Studio Code? and note in `pom.xml`

Comment: Yes, you can download both source code file and javadoc file from here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.13.1/. Then you need to include them into classpath of your Visual Studio and it will work. I am not sure how to properly include those files in Visual Studio classpath. in Eclipse or in InteliJ you would need to create a user library that will include those JARs.

Comment: You don't put `sources` and `javadoc` into the `<dependencies>` section.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I have my own Open Source library, and in my guideline I recommend to add sources and javadoc into <dependencies>. I do so as well, when I use my own library in other projects. It works nicely. It may enlarge the deployment jar file, but it helps in development (debug and javadoc availability in your IDE. In any case I would like to hear why not to do so. You could answer here or move it to separate discussion. BTW, my library is called MgntUtils. You are welcome to look it up

Comment: Eclipse finds the  `sources` and `javadoc` automatically for debugging. IntelliJ as well. I believe VSCode should also be able to do this. Maven does not need them, and they may end up in some WAR. I have never seen anybody adding them as dependencies.

Comment: @MichaelGantman Do you know if it's possible to exclude this JavaDoc and sources dependency on deployment?

Comment: Yes, this could be done. Use scope "provided" (<scope>provided</scope>) for javadoc and source dependencies and they will not be included in the deployment. See this link: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: @JFabianMeier, If I didn't include the dependencies for sources and Javadoc in my project Eclipse did not find them. As for "I have never seen anybody adding them as dependencies" it should not be sufficient grounds for downvoting the answer. We all have some things we never saw done and that doesn't make them wrong. If you want to downvote, than provide the negative effects of such action, and the reasons why it shouldn't be done. "I 've never seen this" may be the indicator that it shouldn't be done, just as well as an indicator of the of your lack of knowledge of this detail

Comment: @MichaelGantman Eclipse automatically looks for the `sources` and the `javadoc` JAR. I have seen that work with dozens of dependencies and our 150 developers use this feature as well. So there are no positive effects of adding `sources` as dependencies, and the negative are: 1. Clutters your POM. 2. Confuses other developers. 3. May end up in deployed artifacts (if not scope `provided`). And, for the last point, I think that after answering more than 1000 Maven questions on StackOverflow and earning the golden Maven Badge, it is unlikely that I have just "not seen" this before.

Comment: @JFabianMeier, fine, you provided your points and they are valid, regardless of whether I agree or not.

Comment: Just a quick check if we still have 2022 and not 2002?
You don't want to tell me that we need to add the sources to the pom file, right?
There is an extension or something like that?

Comment: You don't have to, but you can. Both Eclipse and InteliJ just by having artifact without source and Javadoc can check and find both in the remote artifactory. But you can include them if you want to. And I saw that it solved some problems for me when IDE failed for some reason. If you include sources and javadoc in the pom they will for sure be downloaded locally and I also found it useful sometimes

Answer (score 2):

In VS Code v1.68.1 my `javadocs` for some reason stopped showing up and navigating to definition showed the disassembled sources instead of the packaged sources. Enabling the settings depicted below restored the `javadocs` and `sources` I was expecting.

**Setting IDs**

```
java.eclipse.downloadSources
java.maven.downloadSources
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There's no way to achieve your goals because the jar or dependency itself doesn't have the docstring.

For example, when you click into `println`, the comment part is also the content when you hover over the `println`:

[image]

But there's no such comment in jsoup, so java extension won't be able to catch the docstring and show it.

**[UPDATE]**

**jsoup/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.class:**
[image]

The files included in jar are all compiled to .class file, there's no comments before functions, so Java language server can't catch it to show as the feature intellisense.

Comment: This dont work with this library: [villes-et-departements-de-france](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.devlab-umontp/villes-et-departements-de-france/1.1.0/jar)
But this library has a `Javadoc` : [Sources and Javadoc](https://github.com/DevLab-umontp/Librairie-Java-Villes-de-France)
[The message of Maven central](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-65056)

Comment: Jsoup has a JavaDoc: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.java

Comment: but the jsoup-1.31.1.jar doesn't include these comments in it. i'll edit my answer and you can see no comments displayed.